# Can a language have exceptions without a type hierarchy?

Tags: oop, exception, inheritance, programming-languages

In my experience, every language which supports exceptions has a hierarchy of exception types. This allows a single `catch` clause to match a group of related exceptions by catching their common parent. For example, part of [Python's hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy):

```
FloatingPointError < ArithmeticError < Exception < BaseException
```

Go, on the other hand, famously does not support exceptions and also has ["no type hierarchy"](https://golang.org/doc/faq#principles). Some people think exceptions should be added to Go - would it be possible to do this without adding a type hierarchy?

Are there other languages which have exceptions but no type hierarchy? Do they group related exceptions in some other way?

Comment: In C#, virtually all of the exceptions are "directly" derived from `System.Exception`; is that what you mean?

Comment: Having a hierarchy of exceptions doesn't have anything to do with having exceptions in the first place. Related to your example, Python's original exceptions were all strings.

Comment: @JimB - Good example. I found some information about string vs class exceptions in Python [here](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-exceptions-came-to-be-classes.html).

Comment: C#'s exception hierarchy may be shallower than Python's, but the hierarchy still exists. For example, similar to `FloatingPointError` in Python, C# has `ArgumentNullException < ArgumentException < SystemException < Exception`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SuperTalk has effectively no data types, but has exceptions. Basically you throw an error code and check that. That's also how many early macOS application frameworks worked, even in C++.

So just as an object can be approximated by using a simple data structure with a type selector, exceptions can be made to work.

```
on doFoo
  throw "myError"
end doFoo

on startUp
  try
    doFoo
  catch tError
    if tError = "myError" then
      -- do something about it
    else
      throw tError
    end if
  end try
end startUp
```

Instead of "myError", you can throw any string or number, so you could use a formatted string, like "copyFileError,/path/to/source/file.txt,/path/to/dest/file.t‌​xt" (of course with proper escaping of dangerous characters like "," in this case) and then just compare the first item in this list to tell whether it's the error you want to handle.

If you're just going with error numbers without any additional payload, you can segment the number space to get error "classes" e.g. "fatal errors are negative, recoverable ones positive" or "1-100 are file system errors" or whatever (see HTTP status code for an example of using error code ranges to define error classes).

Comment: Interesting - is there example code anywhere that demonstrates exception-handling in SuperTalk?

Comment: I've added an example, I can't really find a good one on the web, neither in any SuperCard-related forum, nor in ones for the descendent language LiveCode. It's really not much different from standard exception handling, in fact you can do the same in C++ if you want to.

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather post this as a comment, but the sentiment was too long to get across within the limitations of a comment. I am aware that this is primarily opinion based, and I apologize for that.

Go does not support exceptions because it does not need to. Exceptions are a crutch that developers have been lured into becoming dependent on because they don't want to handle errors properly. In Go, it is idiomatic to handle **every** error, on the spot, **every** time. If you do this, your programs run better, and you are aware of exactly when/where errors happen and you can fix them. Using `catch` in other languages ends up being more difficult to debug as you are not always aware of exactly where the error originally happened. By wrapping your code in `try` `catch` blocks, you essentially mask the bugs in your code. `try` and `catch` are also terribly inefficient because all of the optimizations in the binary grind to a halt as the program has to figure out what unexpectedly happened. Using errors properly in Go circumvents this because you capture errors and handle them, thereby "expecting" them as an eventuality and handling them properly.

Comment: I just wrote some Python for the first time after several months of mostly Go and I found Go changed my Python style immensely and also made me appreciate Go's idiomatic use of multi-return statements.  Wrapping EVERY call that throws exceptions in try catch blocks is very verbose.  Go put me in the habit of handling every failure then and there and that translated to my Python but it wasn't pretty will all the try catches.  Also, it's very common to see massive blocks of Java wrapped in a single generic try catch and that drives me crazy.

Comment: I would like to add that spghettisation of code often takes place. You do something, throw the Exception to deal with it somewhere else and there the problem starts. Coming from Java, I found Go's "errors are first class members, deal with them" a real eye opener. Panics provide enough flexibility.

Comment: @Dale Co-workers used to to that to me in Java too... Mostly where my distaste is coming from. Go has changed the way I write code in every language now. Mostly for the better.